# No CONTROLLER named changeset deployment error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, change-set

I'm trying to deploy a few lightning components but I am getting an error

> No CONTROLLER named apex://CreateQuoteRequestController found : [markup://c:createQuoteRequestApp, markup://c:createQuoteRequest]

I have a lightning app named createQuoteRequestApp that displays a lightning component to a visualforce page

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:createQuoteRequest"/>
</aura:application>
```

I also have the CreateQuoteRequestController apex controller included in the change set. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is strange .If you have included controller then it should deploy .

Comment: Any errors that might be preventing the controller apex class from deploying? What if you try and deploy the controller class first in isolation?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm going to try this out. Deploy the code, and then deploy the components

Answer (score 1):

The Known Issue was reported in Summer 17, but it might be [Package install fails with error: No CONTROLLER named js://xxxxxx found or We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI).

Answer (score 0):

Does the org where you are deploying has namespace defined? If yes, please try to add a reference to the controller controller="NAME OF YOUR CONTROLLER"